# Using react-native-apple-healthkit, While running the project from Xcode Build getting Failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using following things:

React Native: **0.46.1**

react-native-apple-healthkit: **^0.2.1**

**What I did:**

I install **react-native-apple-healthkit**

then I run command: **react-native link**

**Problem is:** When I'm running my react native project from Xcode, It's giving me *error : Duplicate interface definition for class "RCTBridge"*

Can anyone please help me on above?

Thanks, In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved after unlinking library and again manually linking library.